# rpy2 installation error (OSX 10.8, R 3.1)

Tags: rpy2

The error message is

`gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -g -arch x86_64 -headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules -lR -llzma -liconv -licucore -lm -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so
ld: library not found for -llzma
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Comment: I've just reinstalled R 3.0.3 and rpy2 can be installed successfully.

Comment: That's a workaround, not a fix. What version of rpy2 are you trying to install ? rpy2-2.3.10 fixed issues around installing with R-3.1.

Comment: I am getting cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -Wl,-F. -F/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.0/R.framework/.. -framework R -llzma -licucore -lm -liconv -Qunused-arguments -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.0/R.framework/Resources/include build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.0/R.framework/Resources/modules -lR -llzma -liconv -licucore -lm -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so

ld: library not found for -lR

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried rpy2 2.4.0 and successfully installed it with R 3.1.0 on OSX 10.8.5. However, when I run tests after installation

```
python -m 'rpy2.tests'
```

it comes with one failure

```
rpy2 version: 2.4.0
- built against R version: 3-1.0--65387
- running linked to R version: R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
/Users/xxx/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py:29: UserWarning: Module rpy2 was already imported from /Users/xxx/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.4.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/rpy2/__init__.pyc, but /Users/xxx/Downloads/rpy2-2.4.0 is being added to sys.path

from pkg_resources import resource_streamFontconfig error: Cannot load default config file     

Ran 374 tests in 8.728s
OK (skipped=1, expected failures=1)
```

Comment: Note that the failure is noted as expected. `python -m rpy2.tests -v` can tell you more about the individual tests.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and was using the [brew](http://brew.sh/) version of R:

> --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/rpy2
>
> ld: library not found for -lR

Directly installing from with the .pkg from [http://www.r-project.org](http://www.r-project.org/) solved the problem for me.